# Insert shapes in Quarto revealJS

Tags: quarto, reveal.js

In powerpoint we could insert shapes like circles, squares and arrows to refer to a word for example. I would like to insert an arrow in a revealjs slide to a specific word. Here is some reproducible code:

```
---
title: "Insert shapes in revealjs Quarto"
format: revealjs
---

## Slide

I would like to fade in an arrow to this **word**
```

Output:

[image]

So I was wondering if anyone knows how to insert shapes like arrows to refer to a word in revealjs Quarto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try out the [roughnotation](https://github.com/EmilHvitfeldt/quarto-roughnotation) extension. Note that it doesn't showcase correctly in RStudio IDE and sometimes you need to adjust the zoom in your browser to get right results. Press `R` to see the circle on the slide.

```
---
title: "Insert shapes in revealjs Quarto"
format: revealjs
filters:
   - roughnotation
---

## Slide

I would like to fade in an arrow to this [word]{.rn rn-type=circle rn-color=red}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @Julian, Thank you for your answer! This is looking nice! Although do you know it is possible to insert shapes like arrows like we could do in Powerpoint? Thanks

Comment: Not really, I would try out if a combination of [fragments](https://quarto.org/docs/presentations/revealjs/advanced.html#fragments) and css could work.